# How to find word frequency per country list in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a .CSV which has three columns: tidytext, location, vader_senti

I was already able to get the amount of *positive, neutral and negative *text* instead of word* pero country using the following code:

```
data_vis = pd.read_csv(r"csviamcrpreprocessed.csv", usecols=fields)

def print_sentiment_scores(text):
    vadersenti = analyser.polarity_scores(str(text))
    return pd.Series([vadersenti['pos'], vadersenti['neg'], vadersenti['neu'], vadersenti['compound']])

data_vis[['vadersenti_pos', 'vadersenti_neg', 'vadersenti_neu', 'vadersenti_compound']]  = data_vis['tidytext'].apply(print_sentiment_scores)

data_vis['vader_senti'] = 'neutral'
data_vis.loc[data_vis['vadersenti_compound'] > 0.3 , 'vader_senti'] = 'positive'
data_vis.loc[data_vis['vadersenti_compound'] < 0.23 , 'vader_senti'] = 'negative'


data_vis['vader_possentiment'] = 0
data_vis.loc[data_vis['vadersenti_compound'] > 0.3 , 'vader_possentiment'] = 1

data_vis['vader_negsentiment'] = 0
data_vis.loc[data_vis['vadersenti_compound'] <0.23 , 'vader_negsentiment'] = 1

data_vis['vader_neusentiment'] = 0
data_vis.loc[(data_vis['vadersenti_compound'] <=0.3) & (data_vis['vadersenti_compound'] >=0.23) , 'vader_neusentiment'] = 1

sentimentbylocation = data_vis.groupby(["Location"])['vader_senti'].value_counts()
sentimentbylocation
```

sentimentbylocation gives me the following results:

```
Location                      vader_senti
Afghanistan                   negative          151
                              positive           25
                              neutral             2
Albania                       negative            6
                              positive            1
Algeria                       negative          116
                              positive           13
                              neutral             4
```

TO GET THE MOST COMMON POSITIVE WORDS, I USED THIS CODE:

```
def process_text(text):
    tokens = []
    for line in text:
        toks = tokenizer.tokenize(line)
        toks = [t.lower() for t in toks if t.lower() not in stopwords_list]
        tokens.extend(toks)

    return tokens

tokenizer=TweetTokenizer()
punct = list(string.punctuation)
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english') + punct + ['rt','via','...','…','’','—','—:',"‚","â"]
pos_lines = list(data_vis[data_vis.vader_senti == 'positive'].tidytext)

pos_tokens = process_text(pos_lines)
pos_freq = nltk.FreqDist(pos_tokens)

pos_freq.most_common()
```

Running this will give me the most common words and the number of times they appeared, such as

```
[(good, 1212),
(amazing, 123)
```

However, what I want to see is how many of these positive words appeared in a country.

For example:

[image]

I have a sample CSV here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/112k-6VLB3UyljFFUbeo7KhulcrMedR-l/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a column for each `most_common` word, then do a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) location and use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) to apply a sum for each count:

```
words = [i[0] for i in pos_freq.most_common()]

# lowering all cases in tidytext
data_vis.tidytext = data_vis.tidytext.str.lower()

for i in words:
    data_vis[i] = data_vis.tidytext.str.count(i)

funs = {i: 'sum' for i in words}
grouped = data_vis.groupby('Location').agg(funs)
```

Based on the example from the CSV and using most_common as `['good', 'amazing']` the result would be:

```
grouped

#               good amazing
# Location      
# Australia     0    1
# Belgium       6    4
# Japan         2    1
# Thailand      2    0
# United States 1    0
```